# sql query to produce xml output

Tags: .net, sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have these tables

**Table 1**
`tbl1_site
[facilityId]
[name]`

**Table 2**
`tbl2_applicant
[pvid] 
[facilityId] 
[npi] 
[firstname]`

FK join key: tbl1_site.facilityId = tbl2_applicant.facilityId

**Table 3**
`tbl3_abstraction
[pvid] 
[patientnumber]
[diabetesdiagnosis]
[dateofbirth]`

FK join key: tbl2_applicant.pvId = tbl3_abstraction.pvId

i have problem to create a sql query to reproduce this xml output.

thanks

```
<account>
    <metadata />
    <practice-sites>
        <practice-site>
            <metadata>
                <data-element id="name">
                    <value>My Own Diabetes Medical Center</value>
                </data-element>
            </metadata>
            <applicants>
                <metadata />
                <applicant>
                    <metadata>
                        <data-element id="npi">
                            <value>1234567890</value>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="firstname">
                            <value>Joseph</value>
                        </data-element>
                    </metadata>
                    <clinical-abstractions>                           
                        <clinical-abstraction>
                            <data-element id="diabetesdiagnosis">
                                <value>Backward</value>
                            </data-element>
                            <data-element id="dateofbirth">
                                <value>02/01/2009</value>
                            </data-element>
                            <data-element id="patientnumber">
                                <value>1</value>
                            </data-element>
                        </clinical-abstraction>
                    </clinical-abstractions>
                </applicant>
            </applicants>
        </practice-site>
    </practice-sites>
</account>
```

Comment: What will be consuming this XML and for what purpose?

Comment: And can you show the data types and provide the sample data that led to the XML output?

Comment: I believe I can answer your question, Bernard.  I'm having the same issue. In my case, this is needed for NCQA Diabetes Recognition. It is a requirement of the XML that needs to be submitted.  I don't know about mBotros, but where I am I do not have access to any other way of gathering this data besides SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you really need all those tags?
I mean the "metadata" and "data-element"

try this query, it shows the data on the format you need:

```
select  t1.name as PracticeSite,
        (SELECT t2.npi as NPI, 
                t2.firstname,
                (SELECT t3.patientnumber, 
                        t3.diabetesdiagnosis, 
                        t3.dateofbirth
                        FROM tbl3_abstraction t3
                        WHERE t3.pvId=t2.pvId
                        FOR XML PATH('clinical-abstraction'), TYPE
                        ) as 'clinical-abstractions'
                FROM tbl2_applicant t2
                WHERE t1.[facilityId]=t2.[facilityId]
                FOR XML PATH('Applicant'), TYPE
        ) AS 'Applicants'
from tbl1_site t1
FOR XML path('PracticeSites'), root('account'), ELEMENTS;
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, but I need the data-element tag and the value inside a value tag as well. thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest thing to do would be craft your SQL statement using "SELECT [...] FROM whatever AS XML" to get the data as the default SQL Server generated XML. Once you have that, transform it to your required XML format using XSLT. This could be done via a SQL Server function or a function in your .NET application.

Answer (score 2):

The following will produce the exact output you desire.  It is not the most maintainable code ever written, but it should give you what you desire.  I have taken the liberty of creating the tables and populating them with data to prove that this solution will work.  I have guessed at the various data types and inserted CONVERT statements to make them back into strings when I concatenate values together for the XML.

Note: In SQL Server Management Studio, you will want to switch the output to Text instead of Grid output (shortcut key is Ctrl-T) so that the query output is represented as a bunch of text

```sql
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Create some tables to work with (you should have these already)
CREATE TABLE tbl1_site ([facilityId] INT, [name] VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE tbl2_applicant([pvid] INT, [facilityId] INT, [npi] BIGINT, [firstname] VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE tbl3_abstraction([pvid] INT, [patientnumber] INT, [diabetesdiagnosis] VARCHAR(100), [dateofbirth] DATETIME)

-- Add some basic data
INSERT INTO tbl1_site SELECT 100, 'My Own Diabetes Medical Center'
INSERT INTO tbl2_applicant SELECT 10, 100, 1234567890, 'Joseph'
INSERT INTO tbl3_abstraction SELECT 10, 1, 'Backward', '02/01/2009' 

-- For testing (here's some more data - uncomment if desired)
--INSERT INTO tbl3_abstraction SELECT 10, 2, 'Forward', '03/04/2009' 
--INSERT INTO tbl1_site SELECT 200, 'My Other Diabetes Medical Center'
--INSERT INTO tbl2_applicant SELECT 10, 200, 9876543210, 'Conrad'
--INSERT INTO tbl3_abstraction SELECT 10, 3, 'Up', '02/01/2009' 
--INSERT INTO tbl3_abstraction SELECT 10, 4, 'Down', '03/04/2009' 

-- Declare some table variables and populate them with the required information from the base tables
-- We will use these to loop through
DECLARE @tbl1_site TABLE (tbl1Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, [facilityId] INT, [name] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl1_site(facilityId, name)
SELECT facilityId, name FROM tbl1_site

DECLARE @tbl2_applicant TABLE (tbl2Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, [pvid] INT, [facilityId] INT, [npi] BIGINT, [firstname] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl2_applicant([pvid], [facilityId], [npi], [firstname])
SELECT [pvid], [facilityId], [npi], [firstname] FROM tbl2_applicant

DECLARE @tbl3_abstraction TABLE (tbl3Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, [pvid] INT, [patientnumber] INT, [diabetesdiagnosis] VARCHAR(100), [dateofbirth] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl3_abstraction([pvid], [patientnumber], [diabetesdiagnosis], [dateofbirth])
SELECT [pvid], [patientnumber], [diabetesdiagnosis], [dateofbirth] FROM tbl3_abstraction

-- Additional variables to track rows and field values
DECLARE @Maxtbl1Id INT
DECLARE @Curtbl1Id INT
DECLARE @facilityId INT

DECLARE @Maxtbl2Id INT
DECLARE @Curtbl2Id INT
DECLARE @pvid INT

DECLARE @Maxtbl3Id INT
DECLARE @Curtbl3Id INT

-- Declare an output table to hold everything in
DECLARE @OutputTable TABLE (OutputTableId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, XmlElement VARCHAR(8000))

-- Here is the top of the XML
INSERT INTO @OutputTable(XmlElement)
SELECT '<account>
<metadata />
<practice-sites>'

-- Loop through all the practice sites
SELECT @Maxtbl1Id = MAX(t.tbl1Id), @Curtbl1Id = MIN(t.tbl1Id) FROM @tbl1_site t

WHILE (@Maxtbl1Id >= @Curtbl1Id)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @OutputTable(XmlElement)
    SELECT '        <practice-site>
        <metadata>
            <data-element id="name">
                <value>' + t.name + '</value>
            </data-element>
        </metadata>'
      FROM @tbl1_site t
     WHERE tbl1Id = @Curtbl1Id

    SELECT @facilityId = t.facilityId
      FROM @tbl1_site t
     WHERE tbl1Id = @Curtbl1Id

    INSERT INTO @OutputTable (XmlElement)
    SELECT '            <applicants>
            <metadata />'

    -- Loop through all the applicants
    SELECT @Maxtbl2Id = MAX(t.tbl2Id), @Curtbl2Id = MIN(t.tbl2Id) FROM @tbl2_applicant t WHERE t.facilityId = @facilityId

    WHILE (@Maxtbl2Id >= @Curtbl2Id)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @OutputTable(XmlElement)
        SELECT '                <applicant>
                <metadata>
                    <data-element id="npi">
                        <value>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), t.npi) + '</value>
                    </data-element>
                    <data-element id="firstname">
                        <value>' + t.firstname + '</value>
                    </data-element>
                </metadata>'
          FROM @tbl2_applicant t
         WHERE tbl2Id = @Curtbl2Id

        SELECT @pvid = t.pvid
          FROM @tbl2_applicant t
         WHERE tbl2Id = @Curtbl2Id

        -- Loop through all the abstractions
        INSERT INTO @OutputTable(XmlElement)
        SELECT '                    <clinical-abstractions>                           
                    <clinical-abstraction>
                        <data-element id="diabetesdiagnosis">
                            <value>' + diabetesdiagnosis + '</value>
                        </data-element>
                        <data-element id="dateofbirth">
                            <value>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateofbirth, 1) + '</value>
                        </data-element>    
                        <data-element id="patientnumber">
                            <value>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), patientnumber) + '</value>
                        </data-element>
                    </clinical-abstraction>
                </clinical-abstractions>'
        FROM tbl3_abstraction t
        WHERE t.pvid = @pvid

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable(XmlElement)
        SELECT '                </applicant>
        </applicants>'

        -- Increment our counter
        SET @Curtbl2Id = @Curtbl2Id + 1
    END

    INSERT INTO @OutputTable(XmlElement)
    SELECT '        </practice-site>
</practice-sites>'

    -- Increment our counter
    SET @Curtbl1Id = @Curtbl1Id + 1
END

-- Close off XML
INSERT INTO @OutputTable(XmlElement)
SELECT '</account>'

-- Return our result set
SELECT t.XmlElement
  FROM @OutputTable t
 ORDER BY t.OutputTableId ASC
```

Comment: @mBotros Do you have any feedback or questions on the above solution?  I believe that it completely and accurately answers your question.

Comment: I'm trying to use the above code, but I need to add more fields. However; I'm finding that it's being cutoff.    I'm trying to post an example, but it isn't posting properly. <pre> <code><metadata>
<data-element id="submissionid">
  <value>West Bend</value>
  </data-element>
  <data-element id="softwarename">
   <value>Epic</value>
  </data-element>
  <data-element id="softwareversion">
   <value>2014</value>
  </data-element>
  <data-elemen

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend trying to do this using straight SQL as there are tools that exist to convert your SQL query into XML for you.  Try using FOR XML in your select statement.  Check out this [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191268.aspx) from Microsoft and see if this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This really doesn't look like the kind of thing SQL should be doing.  It's far too complex.  That xml is overly deep with many empty elements.  Remember that XML is **hierarchical** whereas if you're working with SQL Server, that's a **relational** database and the two are completely different.  As per the probable hint behind **@Bernard**'s comment, what's consuming the xml and therefore would that be a better place to do a conversion?

If you can switch to a simpler xml schema, then the approach suggested by **@Diego** gives you the simplest structure that could make sense.

Using **FOR XML PATH** to get you the xml that you specify in the question gets you into a nested set of select statements that is far too difficult to maintain (write once, read never).  So just to show that it is possible - and I **really** wouldn't advise this - below is an example using **FOR XML EXPLICIT**.  This is at least slightly easier to follow but requires changes in every section if you have to add an element.

When using **FOR XML EXPLICIT** you have two requirements:
1. Specify the elements/attributes involved (usually the first SQL section)
2. Specify the relationships between the elements together with values where appropriate.

```
select 1 as tag,
       null as parent,
       null as [account!1],
       null as [metadata!2],
       null as [practice-sites!3],
       null as [practice-site!4],
       null as [metadata!5],
       null as [data-element!6!id],
       null as [data-element!6!value!ELEMENT],
       null as [applicants!7],
       null as [metadata!8],
       null as [applicant!9],
       null as [metadata!10],
       null as [data-element!11!id],
       null as [data-element!11!value!ELEMENT],
       null as [data-element!12!id],
       null as [data-element!12!value!ELEMENT],
       null as [clinical-abstractions!13],
       null as [clinical-abstraction!14],
       null as [data-element!15!id],
       null as [data-element!15!value!ELEMENT],
       null as [data-element!16!id],
       null as [data-element!16!value!ELEMENT],
       null as [data-element!17!id],
       null as [data-element!17!value!ELEMENT]

union all
select 2,
       1,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 3,
       1,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null       

union all
select 4,
       3,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 5,
       4,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 6,
       5,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       'name',
       s.name,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null   
from dbo.tbl1_Site s
where s.facilityID = @facilityID

union all
select 7,
       4,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 8,
       7,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 9,
       7,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 10,
       9,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 11,
       10,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       'npi',
       ap.npi,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null
from dbo.tbl2_Applicant ap
where ap.pvid = @pvid

union all
select 12,
       10,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       'firstname',
       ap.firstname,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null
from dbo.tbl2_Applicant ap
where ap.pvid = @pvid

union all
select 13,
       9,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 14,
       13,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
       null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

union all
select 15,
       14,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       'diabetesdiagnosis',
       a.diabetesdiagnosis,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null
from dbo.tbl3_Abstraction a
where a.patientnumber = @patientnumber

union all
select 16,
       14,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       'dateofbirth',
       convert(varchar(10), a.dateofbirth, 101),
       null,
       null
from dbo.tbl3_Abstraction a
where a.patientnumber = @patientnumber

union all
select 17,
       14,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null,
       'patientnumber',
       a.patientnumber
from dbo.tbl3_Abstraction a
where a.patientnumber = @patientnumber

for xml explicit
```

Note I'd usually keep each attribute/element on a separate line in SQL such as this but given the number of empty elements, I wrapped the nulls just to tidy things up (a little).
It may be possible to reduce this slightly but frankly, there's no point.  It already demonstrates that is really not the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to create the the XML in DB? Why not to generate it in the BL? It will be easier to maintain & I think that in terms of performance it will be more efficient then SQL.